# multimaps(benchmark) source code in C

Tags: c, benchmarking, performance

I am actually seeking the multiMAPS benchmark source code written in C. It is a benchmark that measures memory bandwidth.. Did somebody heard about it?

Comment: Looking for this? http://www.sdsc.edu/pmac/projects/downloads/MultiMAPS_r3153.tar.gz

Comment: I met this, but i wanted the linux version. Or do you know how to compile it on linux system? I tried but failed...

Comment: Did the usual untar, configure, make, make install sequence not work for you? And if it so, did you look at the README the way the website suggests? With that done, where are you hung up?